# Create an authentication page with SAPUI5

Tags: abap, sapui5

I try to create an authentication page with sapui5 and I have to connect with the same username and password as the sap server
Can you help me please.

Comment: People here on SO are more likely to help you if you can provide what you have tried so far. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I try to send the username and the password in the URL (ODATA) but I don't  know how i can check  the exactness of these identifiers

Answer (score 1):

@Sajid Loukili

You need to create xsjs file which handles authentication logic like check your username and password with the ones in your database.

To call this xsjs file you need to use jQuery.ajax() in which you pass your url to the url property of jQuery.ajax() and the parameters in this url.

Then in the xsjs you need to get this parameters from url and check them with your database if they are same then you let them login if not pop a message.